# How can I add a derived column to my Yii model?

Tags: php, activerecord, model, yii, virtual-attribute

In Yii, I need to add a "derived" column to any resultset from my model. The column doesn't actually exist in the database table.

For example, say I have an `Activity` model. There are only two types of Activities: (1) Income, or (2) Expense.

If I want to add a column called `income_total` or `expense_total` (depending on what *type* of activity is being accessed), how would I do that?

Here's a working example of an `Activity` model in Ruby on Rails (I'm basically wondering how to do the same thing, but in Yii):

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :effective_at, :amount, :category
  scope :incomes,  :conditions => { :category => 'Income'  }
  scope :expenses, :conditions => { :category => 'Expense' }

  def self.incomes_total
    incomes.sum :amount
  end

  def self.expenses_total
    expenses.sum :amount
  end

end
```

**Update 2012-07-01:**

The [answer provided by Leonardo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11044571/426935) points to the use of [Virtual Attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/), this adds an attribute to each "row" of the resultset that I'm retrieving from the database.

If the `Activity` model has a `BELONGS_TO` relationship with `Parent`, a Parent View may look like the following:

```
<h2><?php echo $parent->name; ?></h2>
<ul>
  <?php foreach($portfolio->activities as $activity): ?>
    <li>
      <?php echo CHtml::link($activity->name, array('activity/view', 'id' => $activity->id)); ?>
      <?php echo $activity->amount; ?>
      <?php echo $activity->incomes_total; ?>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

However, it doesn't make sense for this Virtual Attribute to be accessed within the foreach() loop.

These Virtual Attributes that I want provide one "aggregated" value for the whole resultset, so I want to be able access it using `$parent->activities->incomes_total`, like so:

```
<h2><?php echo $parent->name; ?></h2>
<?php echo $parent->activities->incomes_total; ?>
<ul>
  <?php foreach($portfolio->activities as $activity): ?>
    <li>
      <?php echo CHtml::link($activity->name, array('activity/view', 'id' => $activity->id)); ?>
      <?php echo $activity->amount; ?>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

What do I need to do within the Activity model code to achieve this, or should I be thinking about this a different way?

Comment: I've just seen that Yii has an implementation of [Named Scopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes) too. So I'm reading into that. It may point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is pretty similar to Ruby. PHP has magic methods, which in Yii is implemented by CComponent (base class of many including CActiveRecord).

In short you can do this within your model

```
   class Activity extends CActiveRecord {
     public function getIncome_Total() {
       // ...
     }
   }
```

And, to access it from controller

```
$activity = Activity::model->findByPk(1);
$income_total = $activity->income_total;
```

Comment: I had no idea that could be done. Great. Yii calls it "[Virtual Attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/#hh0)"

Comment: This helps there the virtual attribute is specific for each CActiveRecord instance, however I need the virtual attribute span across the whole resultset. I've updated the question to reflect this detail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this can be done within the model.

Although it is more processing, an option or workaround is to add another `foreach()` loop to the View like so:

```
$incomes_total = 0;
foreach($parent->activities as $activity)
  $incomes_total += $activity->amount;
echo $incomes_total;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11290308/1362777) You can simply use a stat relation. Specify a STAT relation in Parent model as

```
'incomes_total'=>array(self::STAT, 'Activity', 'parent_id','select'=>'SUM(amount)','condition'=>"incomes_total.category='Income'")
```

Similiarly

```
'expense_total'=>array(self::STAT, 'Activity', 'parent_id','select'=>'SUM(amount)','condition'=>"incomes_total.category='Expense'")
```

NOTE: Change the attribute names `parent_id` and `amount` as in your model

Comment: I've tried to play with it but I need this to be in the Activity model rather than in the Parent model so that in the Activity actionIndex() View, I can retrieve the total there too.

Comment: @Turgs I'm not clear what you said. Please specify exactly what you want so that i can edit my answer

Comment: Rather than putting the STAT relation in the Parent model, I need it to be defined somehow within the Activity model. Almost like a STAT relation to itself. That said, I don't like how this STAT relation approach will trigger a separate database query. I would ultimately like a way that uses all the data that's already been retrieved.

Comment: @Turgs You are wrong with the sentance `all the data that's already been retrieved`. Yii doesn't retrieve any related models when the object is initialized. It only retrieves it when it is accessed. And I have no idea how to make a STAT relation to the same class. May be its possible

Comment: I guess I'm not trying to retrieve the data when the object is initialised. I'm just wanting something within the same class, so it's available in the views for that model as a CActiveDataProvider('Activity') object. Although the data isn't available when the Activity model is initialised, it is available **at the time** the data has been retrieved. Maybe what I'm looking for is hard due to a PHP limitation. The way this can be done in Ruby (as shown in my question) is easy using a "self" method. For now, using a simple foreach to do the SUM when needed seems simplest.