# How can I SUM this class property in PHP so I get the total value for all class instances?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, yii

I'm using the PHP MVC framwork, Yii. I have a model called **Category** that has a `HAS_MANY` relationship to **Product** model. Both model classes extend [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CActiveRecord).

I'm looking for help in understanding some specific ways that OOP is working in PHP.

In my a View for my Category Model, I'm trying to find the total inventory count for the Category. For instance, I could do this:

```
<?php
$total_inventory = 0;
foreach($category->products as $product)
  $total_inventory = $total_inventory + $product->inventory;
echo $total_inventory;
?>
```

Why can't I just do this?

```
<?php echo array_sum($category->products->inventory); ?>
```

That results in an error: `PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`.

Then I thought maybe the following would work:

```
<?php echo array_sum($category->products->getAttribute('inventory')); ?>
```

However, that results in: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object`.

Is it possible to use `array_sum()` in the way I'm attempting by just changing something slightly, or is it not possible because `$category->products` is actually an object, not an array? Is that right?

I'm happy to be provided with articles or documentation that help explain what I'm missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `$category->products` is an array of objects. Thats why you cant use `array_sum` on the object attributes. You can get the sum the easy way by adding a [STAT](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStatRelation) relation in the `Category` Model

```
'total_inventory'=>array(self::STAT, 'Product', 'cat_id','select'=>'SUM(inventory)')
```

and you can get the `total_inventory` anywhere by calling `$category->total_inventory`